# не получается сохранить данные в SQlite C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Я в процессе учебы, для закрепления материала решил сделать не большое приложение "заначка" смысл прост, есть баланс, кнопки пополнить и снять. По логике после того как пользователь ввел число и нажал кнопку "пополнить" должен поменяться баланс и в это же время, сумму баланса сохранить в базе данных. Таблицу я создал заранее, ошибка возникает в момент попытки сохранить данные в БД.
[image: ошибка в момент сохранения]

textUpBalance это строка куда вводится число, на сколько пополнить баланс?
класс Money в данном случае создан для самой таблицы:

```
internal class Money
    {
        public int id { get; set; }    
        private int rubles;
        public int Rubles
        {
            get { return rubles; }
            set { rubles = value; }
        }

        public Money() { }

        public Money(int rubles)
        {
            this.rubles = rubles;  
        }
    }
```

к базе данных получаю доступ через класс ApplicationContext где и создан список для работы с бд

```
internal class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Money> Moneys { get; set; }
        public ApplicationContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    }
```

Сама База данных

[image: База данных]

где я допускаю ошибку? заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что нет такой таблицы `Moneys`. Вы точно к той базе коннектитесь, где есть эта таблица? А может в имя таблицы в БД русские буквы закрались, например? Чудес по идее не бывает, надо всё перепроверить.

Comment: да вроде все указано как нужно, в файле App.config: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\DamirZanachka.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
соответственно внутри этой БД таблица называется Moneys, остальной выше на скринах

Comment: EF какой версии? Первоначальная миграция была выполнена?

Comment: миграции не было, а что такое EF я не знаю ) в учебном ролике такого не было

Comment: DbContext, DbSet - это классы Энтити Фреймворка. Вы его как-то подключили. Как? Нам это неведомо. / Вы подключали к проекту какие-то библиотеки, nuget-пакеты? / Покажите конфиг-файл.

Comment: На скриншоте 2 внутренних исключений. Посмотрите их! И нам покажите, если сами не разберётесь. Только не надо скриншотов! Публикуйте текст.

Comment: И вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11968/184217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что, я пытался использовать разные методы работы с базой данных, смешал всё в одну кучу, ms sql server + sqlite, сейчас разобрался в вопросе.
Для того чтобы сохранить в SQlite нужно для начала создать подключение, открыть его и создать объект класса SqliteCommand, и через него отправлять запросы в sqlite, пример:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=название вашей БД.db");
connection.Open();
SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText ="INSERT INTO Moneys (Баланс) VALUES (@Баланс)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Баланс", значение которое сохраняем для 
этого поля);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```